# I've just started using DEV C++ compiler. Some programs that run fine in turbo compiler are not running in Dev compiler..What to do?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, turbo-c++

For example this  program runs fine in turbo but doesn't run in DEV compiler. please explain me why.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main ()
{
int i,j,x[50],y[50],z[50],k,count=0,s;
float prb_ini,absolute_diff,prb;
y[0]=0;
prb_ini=-2;
i=0;

b:
s=0;
i=i+1;

    for(j=1;j<=6;j++)
    {
    a:
    x[j]=rand();
    y[j]=x[j]%52+1;
        for(k=0;k<j;k++)
        {
        if(y[j]==y[k])
        goto a;
        }
    if(y[j]<=26)
    z[j]=1;
    else
    z[j]=0;

    s=s+z[j];
    }
    if(s==3)
    count=count+1;

prb=(float)count/i;
absolute_diff=abs(prb-prb_ini);
if(i<=10)
goto b;
if(absolute_diff > 0.0001)
{
prb_ini=prb;

goto b;}
else
printf("\t %f ",prb);
}
```

I'm using windows xp. but in my university they have windows 8 only. and they have dev compiler only.

Comment: That's because Turbo C++ is ancient, and never was capable to produce portable C++ programs.

Comment: but i'm not having problem with turbo c++. my programs are running fine in turbo. it's not running in DEV.

Comment: Whatever the "example" program is supposed to do, it's a very bad example program to read and learn from.

Comment: I think so that it can be compiled with both.

Comment: If you remove `#include <conio.h>`, this should compile with a standard compliant compiler, since compilers don't generally give errors for coding style. You don't seem to be using anything that might come from that header anyway.

Comment: `goto a;` `goto b;`  My eyes, my eyes...!

Comment: I compiles "as is" (with a couple of type conversion warnings) in MSVC and it prints `0.333333`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY   ..No it can't be. ..please copy and paste the codes in both the compilers and try to run. it's not running in DEV ...but running in turbo.

Comment: *please explain me why.* -- The C++ language was standardized in 1998.  The "Dev compiler" uses an old, but 1998 ANSI-compliant version of g++.  The "Turbo C++" compiler is not standard, as it is over 20 years old and predates the standard.  Expect to see more programs you write in Turbo C++ that will fail to compile, and in some cases, run incorrectly using a standard C++ compiler.

Comment: `#include <conio.h>` isn't portable

Comment: I'd stop using Dev-cpp. It's buggy as f.... It's really buggy. The compiler included with it is also outdated and buggy. Better switch to Code::Blocks. Bloodshed stopped updating DevCpp long time ago.

Comment: @erip as  commented, `#include <conio.h>` can be removed as it is not referenced.

Comment: @arnob Option is set in the problem? What do you get a compile error?

Comment: @BłażejMichalik I agree that the compiler used by Dev-C++ is outdated, but at the very least, it was 1998 standard (or close to it).  The IDE, that's a different story as it was buggy.  However, usage of Turbo C++ in this day and age is a joke being played by whatever school the OP is enrolled in.

Comment: @WeatherVane     '#include <conio.h>' has been removed. still it's not running

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ..i don't know how to explain it. just when i press the run button..the black screen is coming and vanishing.

it'd be better if you simple run it once in dev.

Comment: It might have been operating normally.

Comment: @arnob  You're creating a console program, so open up a console window and run the program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie could you step by step instruct me how. i'm new in dev.

Comment: @arnob: Have you even been able to get any programs at all running in Dev-C++? Even a simple Hello World? When you move to a new coding environment, you should always get Hello World working first, that way you know the whether your problems are with your code, or with your usage of the environment.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Agreed. My comment is just about fulfilling my personal crusade against DevCpp. I would have a lot less nervous childhood if it weren't for it.

Comment: @arnob Open a command prompt, where you see the `C:>`.  Then go to the directory where your .EXE file was created and run the program by typing the name and pressing "Enter".  No different than running any other console program.  Or have you ever run a console program before?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for you help. i just added the getchar. and it's running now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console window is closing before you can see any output. Add this line as the last line of the program:

```
printf("\t %f ",prb);
getchar();                  // <---- add this
}
```

Compile and run the program, then press `Enter` when you are ready to close the console.

Comment: thanks a lot ! yea , it's running now. :D

Comment: in fact there's still that conio.h. ..and it's running fine with that too..

Comment: That's because you do have a library header of that name, but don't use any of its functions.

Comment: 'ot's functions ' means ?

Comment: I was editing my typing is terriiblle.

Comment: it's okay. thanks for your help.